# SOLR popularity field based on other fields

Tags: solr, indexing, popularity

I want to sort my solr search results based on popularity.

We need to compose the popularity by combining two custom fields: ranking and release date with a formula such as  (ranking * release date). This popularity needs be precomputed and  put in a separate index.

Can anyone help on how this can be done?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the field at client side and index it as a separate field in Solr.
You can use Function Queries as well. Check product which will allow you to use [product](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#product) of two fields and sort on that value